# Apache Spark Reduce with java.lang.Math.max unexpected behaviour

Tags: java, apache-spark

I've been encountering some unexpected behaviour when using Spark `reduce` function with `java.lang.Math.max`. Here's sample code:

```
JavaPairRDD<Island, Long> populationWithFitness = parallelizedIslandPop.mapToPair(isl -> evaluateFitness(isl, fitnessCalculator));
System.out.println(populationWithFitness.values().collect().toString());
long currentMaxFitness = populationWithFitness.values().reduce(Math::max);
System.out.println("After Reduce: " + currentMaxFitness);
```

Code above is called multiple times and it most of the time produces unexpected result like this:

```
[-2754285, -2535458, -2626449, -3182283] //printed RDD after collect
After Reduce: -2392513 //value produced by reducer
```

As you can see reducer produces value `-2392513` however this value is not even in the RDD when comparing with printed values of RDD. Why is it? Is `collect()` affecting `reduce()`? I tried it also other way around first reducing and then collecting original RDD and I still observe this strange behaviour. I was thinking that passing static method from `java.Math` library might cause problem when serializing but referring to this [Spark Quick Start Tutorial](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#more-on-rdd-operations) they also use `Math.max` in `reducer` and apparently it's supposed to work.

Any ideas?

Thank you

EDIT:

Additional information: this snippet is part of larger program that has multiple iterations and it's called in each iteration. First iteration produces correct result where `maxValue` produced from `reducer` is correct value but all other iterations are producing strange results

EDIT2:

When I print `populationWithFitness.values().collect().toString()` three times in a row like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<Island, Long> populationWithFitness = parallelizedIslandPop.mapToPair(isl -> evaluateFitness(isl, fitnessCalculator));
System.out.println(populationWithFitness.values().collect().toString());
System.out.println(populationWithFitness.values().collect().toString());
System.out.println(populationWithFitness.values().collect().toString());
long currentMaxFitness = populationWithFitness.values().reduce(Math::max);
System.out.println("After Reduce: " + currentMaxFitness);
```

I get output that looks like this:

```
Generation 1
[-3187591, -3984035, -3508984, -3054649]
[-3187591, -3984035, -3508984, -3054649]
[-3187591, -3984035, -3508984, -3054649]
After Reduce: -3054649
Generation 2
[-3084310, -3931687, -3508984, -3054649]
[-3084310, -3847178, -3508984, -2701881]
[-3148206, -3984035, -2806859, -2989184]
After Reduce: -2949478
Generation 3
[-3187591, -3984035, -3696853, -3054649]
[-3187591, -3984035, -3178920, -3015411]
[-3148206, -3804759, -3657984, -2701881]
After Reduce: -2710313
Generation 4
[-3187591, -2982220, -3310753, -3054649]
[-3148206, -2985628, -3657984, -2701881]
[-3148206, -2706580, -3451228, -2989184]
After Reduce: -2692651
.
.
.
```

As you can see in first iteration everything works fine but in all next iterations it's producing strange output. I guess problem is that it has something to do with **lazy evaluation** and when I call collect it's hasn't applied transformation but I am not sure.

I also tried to replace `reduce(Math::max)` with `JavaDoubleRDD` and called `max` on this `JavaDoubleRDD` but result was the same:

```
JavaDoubleRDD stats = populationWithFitness.mapToDouble(tup -> tup._2());
long currentMaxFitness = stats.max().longValue();
```

Another important point I am testing this code in **local** mode running it with parameters:

```
spark --class "main.TravellingSalesmanMain" --master local[4] exampletravellingsalesman-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar > sparkoutput.txt
```

Comment: Is this really the actual code?

Comment: Yes except that `sampleRdd` on which I apply `map()` is collection of some objects that produce `Long` values after mapping. Other parts are snippets from my code with replaced variable names for easier reference. Provided sample output is also actual output I get.

Comment: what is the source of your rdd?

Comment: I have updated my question with complete snipped of the source code. I should mention `populationWithFitness.values().collect().toString()` is only for debugging purposes and I don't intend to use it in final version of the code I just needed to check that `reduce(Math::max)` is producing expected results

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? What does `evaluateFitness` do? There are a lot of hidden factors with that code. Are you mutating something? What happens if you print `collect` multiple times in a row?

Comment: @JustinPihony I am afraid I'm not able to produce reproducible example as `evaluateFitness` is calculating fitness of the individuals within object `Population` that's within object `Island` etc so it's quite substantial code and it's still in development. No I am not mutating anything it's just calculating numerical value of the fitness based on current configuration of the population. I have updated my question with example of printing `collect` multiple times and as you can see it's printing different values each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely (99%) happening somewhere inside of `evaluateFitness(isl, fitnessCalculator)`. It seems that it is using some sort of non-reproducible source and is therefore sending back results that are different one differing runs. Remember that Spark is lazy and the execution will re-run on each successive action. You can use caching to help this, however even that can fail (node fails/data falls out of cache). You're best bet is to use checkpointing here, but even moreso you should change the execution itself so that it is idempotent.

Comment: Thank you so much. `Cache` works for me. You are right with non-deterministic `map` function however it wasn't `evaluateFitness` but subsequent `selection` and `crossover` function (I guess you concluded from variable naming I'm talking about Genetic Algorithms) which require some randomness factor in order to work so I can't change implementation bit. I'm chaining `map` phases and call `reduce` only for max fitness and on final population to get best solution. I followed some research papers where they implemented it on Hadoop but Spark lazy eval makes it a bit trickier.